# All tray icons missing in 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I'm a new user running 16.04. Has been hassle free but recently lost all the system tray icons. I've found several questions about dropbox, sound, etc but nothing about all system icons. Running program icons seem to be fine.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you run `restart unity-panel-service` from the terminal?

Comment: Did you install any themes ?

Comment: No luck on the restart unity, restarts with same icons missing.  I haven't installed any themes.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen same. Have you tried to use your appearance configuration tool to change the icon theme?  I don't know why this is an issue all of the sudden in Ubuntu 16.04, but I only see most of the icons I want to use if I change the icon theme to Ubuntu-Mono-Light.  Without that, Dropbox, Sparkleshare, and several others turn into error symbols.

Comment: Hey Paul,  Thanks!  Came back immediately when switched, however mine is visible with mono-dark lol.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 feels more like the bleeding edge than one would expect.  I've got a pretty long list of problems that all link back to the not-ready-for-prime-time GTK and apps. I don't see any "check boxes" in apps because of related issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just installed 16.04 and find that the icons in the launcher (which I have set to auto-hide) are often missing. Just went to System_Settings>Appearance>Look and changed the default theme from Ambiance to Radiance and the icons came back. Switching back to Ambiance and the icons remain, at least for the time being. Though if I use the top search icon on the launcher, recent icons are still missing, even though once opened, the icon appears in the launcher as an open application.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Indicator applet and it will bring all system tray icons (tried on Ubuntu 16.04)

```
~$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
GNOME-Flashback:Unity
```

[image]